# Is this possible to position label for lightning:select on the left?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx, selectlist

```
<lightning:select name="SelectOrNot" value="{!v.selectField}" label="Select One" >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.TheOptions}" var="po">
     <option value="{!po}">{!po}</option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

When I try to use standard lightning tag `<lightning:select>`  it displays label on the top .How to make it on the left.

Comment: I presume you meant "on the left" in both the title and question, so I have edited it as such. If this is not correct, please feel free to **[edit]** your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By placing the `<lightning:select>` in a [horizontal form](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#Horizontal), it will transform the labels to the left.

```
<div class="slds-form_horizontal">
    <lightning:select name="SelectOrNot" value="{!v.selectField}" label="Select One" >
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.TheOptions}" var="po">
         <option value="{!po}">{!po}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in a div and apply the "slds-form_horizontal" class like so:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
  <lightning:card title="Select Example" iconName="standard:default" class="slds-size_1-of-4">
    <div class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal slds-p-around_medium">
      <lightning:select label="Name">
        <option value="test">Premium</option>
      </lightning:select>
      <lightning:select label="Color">
        <option value="test">Space Gray</option>
      </lightning:select>
      <lightning:select label="Size">
        <option value="test">X-Large</option>
      </lightning:select>
      <lightning:select label="Quantity">
        <option value="test">10</option>
      </lightning:select>
      <lightning:select label="Weight">
        <option value="test">10g</option>
      </lightning:select>
      <lightning:select label="Material">
        <option value="test">Alumninum</option>
      </lightning:select>
    </div>
  </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

This is how the example above renders as of Winter '19:
[image]